# Multiplication of sparse matrix by diagonal matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to implement the following operation:
`B = diag(u) @ K @ diag(v)` - multiplication of some matrix K, from the left and right by a diagonal matrices. Explicit creation of dense matrix and 2 matrix-matrix products are prohibitevely expensive. In the case if `K` is a `np.ndarray` I have come up with the following solution:

`u[:, None] * K * v[None, :]`

Which works fine, because the broadcasting takes place, but if `K` is a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` I encounter problem with dimension mistmatch:

`ValueError: dimension mismatch`

I've tried

`u[:, None] * K.multiply(v[None, :])`

The left operand is calculated, but then multplication also fails. What should one do to implement the same operation for sparse matrices?

**EDIT**

I've performed a test on smaller data, and in this case there was no such error, but the result for the `np.ndarray` and `csr_matrix` is different:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 10, size = (5, 5))
A_sp = csr_matrix(A)
x = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 6, size = 5)
y = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 6, size = 5)

x[None, :] * A * y[:, None]
# output
array([[ 72,  48, 128,  60,  48],
       [ 45,  20, 140, 175,  60],
       [ 18,  24,  32,  15,  28],
       [ 42,  24,   0,  70,  16],
       [ 30,  40,  32,  60,   0]])

x[None, :] * A_sp * y[:, None]
# output
array([[436, 288, 400, 432, 236],
       [545, 360, 500, 540, 295],
       [109,  72, 100, 108,  59],
       [218, 144, 200, 216, 118],
       [218, 144, 200, 216, 118]])
```

Comment: [mcve] please.  I don't like making test arrays from wordy descriptions

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for suggestion, edited

Comment: `x[None,:]*A_sp` is matrix multiplication, same as `@`.  The result is a (1,5) `ndarray`.  The next `*y[:,None]` is a broadcasted outer product.

Comment: @hpaulj you're right, could you, please, advise what should be done instead in `scipy` in order to get muptiplication from the left and right by diagonal matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 3 arrays like yours:

```
In [33]: A,x,y
Out[33]: 
(array([[7, 4, 2, 9, 0],
        [6, 2, 5, 7, 4],
        [6, 6, 4, 3, 1],
        [5, 6, 5, 1, 2],
        [4, 8, 6, 5, 6]]),
 array([5, 3, 3, 3, 4]),
 array([5, 4, 4, 2, 2]))
```

And make diagonal 2d arrays:

```
In [34]: X = np.diag(x); Y = np.diag(y)
```

The sparse equivalents:

```
In [35]: A_sp
Out[35]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Make the sparse diagonals from the dense ones:

```
In [36]: x_sp = sparse.csr_matrix(X); y_sp = sparse.csr_matrix(Y)
In [37]: x_sp
Out[37]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

or directly:

```
In [38]: x_sp = sparse.diags(x); y_sp = sparse.diags(y)
In [39]: x_sp
Out[39]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

Your original matrix product:

```
In [40]: X@A@Y
Out[40]: 
array([[175,  80,  40,  90,   0],
       [ 90,  24,  60,  42,  24],
       [ 90,  72,  48,  18,   6],
       [ 75,  72,  60,   6,  12],
       [ 80, 128,  96,  40,  48]])
```

That also works with the sparse `A_sp`:

```
In [41]: X@A_sp@Y
Out[41]: 
array([[175,  80,  40,  90,   0],
       [ 90,  24,  60,  42,  24],
       [ 90,  72,  48,  18,   6],
       [ 75,  72,  60,   6,  12],
       [ 80, 128,  96,  40,  48]])
```

Note that the first `@` produces a 2d dense array:

```
In [42]: X@A_sp
Out[42]: 
array([[35, 20, 10, 45,  0],
       [18,  6, 15, 21, 12],
       [18, 18, 12,  9,  3],
       [15, 18, 15,  3,  6],
       [16, 32, 24, 20, 24]])
```

The same thing with the sparse diagonals:

```
In [43]: x_sp@A_sp
Out[43]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [44]: x_sp@A_sp@y_sp
Out[44]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [45]: _.A
Out[45]: 
array([[175.,  80.,  40.,  90.,   0.],
       [ 90.,  24.,  60.,  42.,  24.],
       [ 90.,  72.,  48.,  18.,   6.],
       [ 75.,  72.,  60.,   6.,  12.],
       [ 80., 128.,  96.,  40.,  48.]])
```

The broadcasted equivalent:

```
In [47]: x[:,None]*A*y[None,:]
Out[47]: 
array([[175,  80,  40,  90,   0],
       [ 90,  24,  60,  42,  24],
       [ 90,  72,  48,  18,   6],
       [ 75,  72,  60,   6,  12],
       [ 80, 128,  96,  40,  48]])
```

But broadcasting doesn't work with sparse multiplication

```
In [49]: y[None,:]*A_sp         # same as @
Out[49]: array([[101,  80,  68,  97,  36]])
```

We can use the vectors with the sparse element-wise multiplication. Broadcasting does work here, but be sure to use the `sparse` method (no operator):

```
In [50]: A_sp.multiply(y[None,:])
Out[50]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [51]: _.A
Out[51]: 
array([[35, 16,  8, 18,  0],
       [30,  8, 20, 14,  8],
       [30, 24, 16,  6,  2],
       [25, 24, 20,  2,  4],
       [20, 32, 24, 10, 12]])
In [52]: A_sp.multiply(y[None,:]).multiply(x[:,None])
Out[52]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [53]: _.A
Out[53]: 
array([[175,  80,  40,  90,   0],
       [ 90,  24,  60,  42,  24],
       [ 90,  72,  48,  18,   6],
       [ 75,  72,  60,   6,  12],
       [ 80, 128,  96,  40,  48]])
```

I'll let you look at the relative speeds.  Here the arrays are small, and `A` is not sparse.